# Site policies and faqs we can adopt from other SE sites?

Tags: discussion

The meta homework question trickered the idea to make a meta thread to gather useful or inspirational faqs and policies from older SE science site, but also sites like skeptics.se, which we can adopt and\or change to fit the special needs of biology.se without reinventing the wheel everytime. I dont know all SE sites, so link in your answers to some meta questions of other SE sites you find useful for this site. Often they seem to be tagged as `faq` or `policy`, and are used to point newbies causing a lot of unpleasant redundant moderation work to a explanation for vote to close or downvote and the opportunity to change his question without a lot of commenting on the question.

[Can I ask several related questions in a single thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/can-i-ask-several-related-questions-in-a-single-thread)
[How do I ask Homework questions on physics.se](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)
[Homework questions - Avoiding giving a complete solution](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution)

We still have no faq nor policy tag here?!